# Reverse Osmosis tank fills for 45 minutes and stops. Drains in 10

Tags: plumbing, water

I changed the catridges on my system. Now the tank fills for about 45 minutes with all the valves except the drain line open. It empties in about 10 minutes. Water is not continuously running to the drain. The pressure of the tank is 7.5 psi. It seems the system shuts off when it is partially full as it does not make a sound. Then I close the mains line and open the faucet and it's all gone in 10 minute.

Any help appreciated?

Comment: If the supply flow is slow and the drain flow not restricted thrn sounds fine.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. What's your question? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: “With all the valves except the drain line open”.   This isn’t how RO works.  You must have the drain valve open to produce RO water.  It’s been a long time since I had an RO system so I don’t remember the ratio but there is a huge volume of waste water for every gallon of water filtered through the membrane, that’s why I got rid of mine (water in my area is some of the most expensive in the country).  However if your tank is draining fast like you suggest it sounds like your system has a leaking check valve (and/or you may also have a bad membrane).

Answer (score 0):

Water is usually measured by volume, not time.

How large is your current storage tank, and how many gallons of water do you have after 10 minutes?

Storage tanks are also typically measured in gallons, but the actual water capacity is less because there is also an air bladder that takes up space inside the storage tank.

If you need more than 10 minutes of water, then replace your storage tank with a larger one.